# Add a custom domain to heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a site hosted on GoDaddy with a custom domain. But we want it to move the whole site to heroku using the custom domain that we already have from GoDaddy.

I know that there is a lot of answers about how to integrate a custom domain to heroku.

On the current site we are visible on the search engines, but If I make the change to heroku, I will be able to have my site displayed on the search engines?

Answer (score 0):

To connect your heroku hosting to godaddy,

You have to open your godaddy account and in the DNS Management page add in the cname the host: www and in the point to: your heroku url And in the heroku page in the settings add three domains:

```
1 *.xyz.com 
2: xyz.com
3. www.xyz.com
```

This should work :) Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Now I have another question. The client told me that he does not own that domain. Is a remote domain. Is it possible to do that “double” redirection?

Comment: I have no idea about it! He doesnt have the godaddy credentials account?

Comment: Yes we have the godaddy credentials. The have a hosting and domain called www.a.mx but the company that ask the project has the real domain. So basically they made that the company domain points to the godaddy hosting/domain. Because it is a share hosting it has security flaws that we can’t fix and we are trying to move to Heroku.

Comment: Ok got so you want to keep the domain name with godaddy and to move the hosting to heroku. It depend of what programming language is the website?

Comment: I’ll try to be more clear. A company has the domain www.companydomain.com and asked my boss to make a website. My boss has a hosting service with a domain called mybossdomain.com. The company configure their domain to point to my boss domain. But now for security issues with shared hosting we want to point from the company domain-> to our domain and finally to Heroku.